# Only showing View after second Push on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm having an annoying problem, that may have a simple answer!

I have a ViewController (which contains a TableView Controller and Header View) which I am pushing on to a Navigation Controller - When I push it on the first time after launching, I get a blank view. When I click the Back button to pop it, it appears fine from then on until I re-launch the app.

Does anyone know an "obvious" reason why this would happen?

BTW- following the code in Debug, it appears to be doing all the correct things.. loading the ViewController variables if nil, etc. before the first view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you reload the table after data are loaded ?

[tableView reloadData];